# What should I do to make myself marketable for an entry-level position? (Information in text)

Tags: resume, job-search, career-development, new-job, entry-level

I am a recent college graduate with a BFA (Bachelor's of Fine Arts) in Creative Writing, and I am looking to find a job in the education or editorial industry.

I have been applying like crazy, even Admin jobs, Receptionist jobs, anything that will allow me to get out of the Part-Time work circuit, where I currently have 3 PT retail jobs. (I need to get something far more financially secure as well as establish a routine for myself).

I have some pretty interesting experience, and I was wondering how I could frame things in order to give the best impression to a potential employer. I have applied for a few positions in the last couple weeks, but have not heard back from them.

I have editorial experience in a workshop and classroom environment, both of peers and students. While this may not be industry experience, can I say that it is experience?

I also have teaching experience, which was also experience abroad, as I taught in Asia for a year. What sorts of skills with that would be wise to leverage and which would be wise to skip?

It seems that I am stuck in a Catch-22 in terms of employ-ability, since every "entry-level" position seems to want experience, yet I can't get a job to get said experience. What can make me stand out in the slush pile of applications despite that?

Comment: I am in a different industry, so cannot provide guidance. But your question is an interesting one for any industry, so have an upvote.

Comment: Not a direct answer but also apply to teaching/training positions.  Not appealing to many but tele marketer.

Comment: This is going to get closed as "advice".  You may want to reword it as opportunities for a creating writing degree and how to market to them.

Comment: You say you have been "applying like crazy", but then you say "I have applied for a few positions in the last couple weeks". I wonder if you could apply for more. Part of this comes down to a numbers game. 1 application per week is not a good way to play.

Comment: What sort of editing? Your question has been edited twice to remove errors.

Answer (score 2):

The experience teaching abroad is terrific experience. It shows you can adapt to other cultures, it shows you area risk taker and it shows you have teaching abilities.

You want to get into the education field but did you get your teaching credential when you were in school? If not, I can suggest that you consider being a substitute teacher and then work on your teaching credential so that you can qualify for a teaching position. Most admin jobs in the education field require at least a Master's degree.

With a degree in writing, you might also consider the technical writing field. Yes, it isn't very creative but it will pay the bills and get you that work experience you need to move to something better.  Consider also that an internship in something like Marketing might be the way to go. Those jobs can use creative people who know how to write.

Or consider jobs that simply look for a degree in any field like being a meeting planner or a management analyst. When I was an analyst, most of our top employees had liberal arts degrees instead of business degrees.

Look at non-profits. They don't pay as well so you might find the competition a little less steep. Again, the first job is to get professional experience, it doesn't have to be where you intend to stay.

Comment: Upvote for technical writing. Under appreciated field and work can be far from trivial